# Fluid bake crash and cache missing

Tags: baking, fluid-simulation, cache

I have 2 problems when baking fluid sim.

First I have the issue that when I bake fluid sim Blender just suddenly closes. No error msg or anything. It happens when the resolution comes up at 256 or something like that. Never on lower resolution. I see this on 3 different computer and I can't figure out what the problem is.

The second problem is that when it has closed I can see in the folders that it has baked ex 136 frames. But when I open the blend file and click resume it starts baking from where it was last saved and not from frame 137. I know that it's because the blend file wasn't saved, but when the bake data is there in the folders, isn't there a way to load all the already baked data so I can proceed from where it crashed?

best
Michael

Answer (score 1):

The problem that it doesn't start from frame 137 is that caused by the crash it doesn't "remember" it has already baked the first half (don't quote me on that, I'm no expert here).

For the other problem, it sounds like something I had quite a while ago until I figured it out, maybe it's the same for you: when baking the cache to the *Format Volumes* type *OpenVDB*, the *Advanced* settings by default use the *Blosc* option for *Compression Volumes*. After I changed it to *Zip*, the simulation baked from start to finish.

Or you could use *Uni Cache* instead of *OpenVDB* if that doesn't matter for you. With *Uni Cache* you also get speed vectors for motion blur, they don't work with *OpenVDB* or at least they didn't in older versions, haven't tried it recently.

[image: fluid cache]